# Disable UIPageViewController Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have `UIPageViewController` with 3 child `viewControllers`. Is it possible to disable/prevent a user from scrolling to one specific `viewController` (i.e. User can scroll from view controller B to A, but cannot from B to C - until I later toggle permission allowing user to go from B to C).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I've been able to disable the scroll via `UIPageViewController` scrollView, but can't isolate disabling to a specific `viewController`.

```
func togglePageControllerScroll(shouldScroll: Bool) {
    
    for view in view.subviews {
        
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
            
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = shouldScroll
            break
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting a check in `UIPageViewController` delegate functions `viewControllerBefore` and `viewControllerAfter` where I would return `nil` if the user tried scrolling from B to C, but it seems like doing so also returns `nil` for `viewController` A...

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
guard let viewControllerIndex = childViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
    
guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }

guard childViewControllers.count > previousIndex else { return nil }

guard let previousViewController = childViewControllers[safe: previousIndex] else { return nil }

if viewController is B && previousViewController is A {
    
    return nil
    
} else {
    
    return previousViewController
}
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
guard let viewControllerIndex = childViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }

let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

guard childViewControllers.count != nextIndex else {
    return nil
}

guard childViewControllers.count > nextIndex else { return nil }

guard let nextViewController = childViewControllers[safe: nextIndex] else { return nil }

if viewController is B && nextViewController is C {
    
    return nil
    
} else {
    
    return nextViewController
}
```

}

Comment: `but it seems like doing so also returns nil for viewController A` actually It doesn't. I couldn't see anything to prove it.What is the real problem?

Comment: There are various ways to do this, depending on exactly what you want as the user-experience... If we're on `B` and *try* to scroll left, do you want "part of `C`" to show, but not allow it to scroll all the way? Or, do you want *nothing* to show, as if there are only `A` and `B` pages? Are you showing the PageControl (the "dots")? If so, do you want it to show 3 dots, even when restricting the user from scrolling to `C`?

Comment: @DonMag either scroll experience is welcomed (i will ultimately allow the user to scroll to C), and i am not showing/needing the dots!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach - which, I think, is pretty straight-forward and would be a reasonable solution...

Add a `maxPages` property to your page view controller. Then, in `viewControllerAfter`, do this:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = pageViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
    
    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
    
    // if we are at the Last controller,
    //  OR
    // we are at the "maxPages" controller
    //  return nil
    guard nextIndex < pageViewControllers.count, nextIndex < maxPages else { return nil }
    
    return pageViewControllers[nextIndex]
}
```

Start `maxPages` at `2`, then in the class that is controlling your page view controller, when you want to allow the user to go to the 3rd page, change the `maxPages` property to `3`.

Here is a quick example...

We'll start with a simple "page" view controller - a label centered vertically:

```
class ExamplePageVC: UIViewController {
    
    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(theLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.9),
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Then, a view controller to hold our page view controller, along with a switch to Allow/Not-Allow scrolling to the 3rd page:

```
class PagesViewController: UIViewController {

    var myPVC: MyPageViewController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // a label and toggle switch to enable/disable the 3rd page
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Allow 3rd Page?"
        
        let sw = UISwitch()
        sw.isOn = false
        sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, sw])
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.spacing = 8
        
        // a UIView to hold the page view controller
        let pvcContainer = UIView()
        pvcContainer.backgroundColor = .gray

        [stack, pvcContainer].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            pvcContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pvcContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            pvcContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            pvcContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75),

            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.topAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])

        let pvc = MyPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        addChild(pvc)
        pvc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pvcContainer.addSubview(pvc.view)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            pvc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.topAnchor),
            pvc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.leadingAnchor),
            pvc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.trailingAnchor),
            pvc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pvcContainer.bottomAnchor),
            
        ])

        pvc.didMove(toParent: self)
        
        myPVC = pvc
    }
    
    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        let n: Int = sender.isOn ? 3 : 2
        myPVC.maxPages = n
    }

}
```

and our custom Page View Controller:

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    
    var maxPages: Int = 2 {
        didSet {
            // get the current page index
            var n = currentIndex
            // set controllers, keeping the current page in view
            //  unless, we are decreasing the count and a higher-index page is showing
            if n > maxPages - 1 {
                n = maxPages - 1
            }
            setViewControllers([pageViewControllers[n]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // so we can get the index of the current page
    var currentIndex: Int {
        guard let vc = viewControllers?.first else { return 0 }
        return pageViewControllers.firstIndex(of: vc) ?? 0
    }
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemRed,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemBlue,
    ]
    
    var pageViewControllers: [UIViewController] = [UIViewController]()
    
    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        dataSource = self
        
        // instantiate all "pages"
        
        for i in 0..<colors.count {
            let vc = ExamplePageVC()
            vc.theLabel.text = "Page: \(i)"
            vc.view.backgroundColor = colors[i]
            pageViewControllers.append(vc)
        }
        
        setViewControllers([pageViewControllers[0]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pageViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else { return nil }
        
        return pageViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pageViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else { return nil }
        
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        
        // if we are at the Last controller,
        //  OR
        // we are at the "maxPages" controller
        //  return nil
        guard nextIndex < pageViewControllers.count, nextIndex < maxPages else { return nil }
        
        return pageViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
    
}
```

It will look like this:

[image] [image]

Arrays are zero-based, so we've set the labels to match the array index.

When the switch is **Off**, we can only scroll back-and-forth between `Page 0` and `Page 1`.

When the switch is **On**, we can scroll on to the 3rd page - `Page 2`:

[image]

Notice that we have a little bit of code inside the `didSet {}` block of our `maxPages` var. When we set `maxPages` to a new value, we need to "re-set" the view controllers array of our Page View Controller, while keeping the current page visible.